# Driver for uart4 instance of omap-4460 to be loaded as module instead on booting

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, uart

I have written a simple Uart driver for uart4 instance for omap-4460 panda board with just open,close,read and write functions.How will it be different from [omap-serial.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.4).
Should I include  `platform_driver_register` in the init?
Since this is also a class of character devices how will it be different ?